# Webpack CSS filename in JS file

Tags: javascript, webpack, extract-text-plugin

I am writing a React app with `create-react-app` which uses Webpack and the `extract-text-plugin` to generate bundled `js` and `css` files. Now I would like to know the filename of the generated CSS file in my JS file, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {fileNameOfMyGeneratedCssFileHere}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is that even possible, maybe with a custom loader or Webpack plugin?

***edit*** To clarify: `create-react-app` is not the problem here, I can eject it or create a custom configuration. My problem is how to know the CSS file name(s) from inside a JS script.

Comment: When I remember correct you can not modify the `create-react-app` webpack, until you eject it. So when you run `npm build`you automatically get a bundled version. Therefore, I do not understand your plans. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Ejecting it or creating a custom configuration like so https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/ is not the problem. The problem I have is how to know the file name inside my JS script.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: extract-text-plugin moves css-es to separate file, which you should import via ```<link href="style.css">```  in your index.html, where style.css is the value specified in plugins options like: ```plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css"),
  ]```

Comment: extract-web-plugin also inserts a hash for long term caching so I cannot know the filename as it is based on the css contents.

Comment: You should post your webpack config and file structure if you would like a more constructive answer